# Cannot parse local json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am just starting out with Sencha Touch and working on the version 2.2.1. For some reason, I cannot get my local json to parse properly. I know it is not the response problem because I can see the json in my chrome developers tool.

Here is my `store`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Tasks', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Task'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'tasksStore',
        model: 'MyApp.model.Task',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'tasks.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'tasks'
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Here's my `Model`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Task', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'task', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'task' }
        ]
    }
});
```

I am using `Jasmine` to test my store. Here's my spec

```
describe('MyApp.store.Tasks', function() {
  it('Number of tasks should be four', function() {
    var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Tasks');

    expect(store.getCount()).toBe(4);

  });
});
```

And, here's my sample `json` file. It is in the same directory as Sencha's `index.html` file, which is the root directory.

```
{
   "tasks":[
      {
         "task":"Some Product",
         "id":0
      },
      {
         "task":"Another Product",
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "task":"A third product",
         "id":2
      },
      {
         "task":"A fourth product",
         "id":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it because of instantiation issues? Or am I missing some critical piece in here? I tried jsonp for proxy type, but it needs a wrapper around the response and I don't quite know how to do it. I am testing on both Safari and Chrome, unfortunately the unit test fails on both browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store loading is asynchronous, so you cannot access their data immediately after having created them.

To know when the store has been loaded, you can listen on the [`load` event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) of the store:

```
var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Tasks');

// you cannot use the store's data yet
// expect(store.getCount()).toBe(4);

store.on('load', function(records, success) {
    if (success) {
        // here the store has been loaded
        expect(store.getCount()).toBe(4);
    }
});
```

Or, you can also pass a callback to the [`load` method](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load):

```
var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Tasks', {autoLoad: false});

store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            // here the store has been loaded
            expect(store.getCount()).toBe(4);
        }
    }
});
```

Now, that means that you'll have to [make your Jasmine test asynchronous](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support) as well:

```
describe('MyApp.store.Tasks', function() {
    it('Number of tasks should be four', function() {
        var result = null,
            store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Tasks');

        store.on('load', function(store, records, success) {
            result = success;
        });

        // using jasmine async...
        waitsFor(function() {
            return result !== null;
        });

        // this functin will be executed when the one in waitsFor returns true
        runs(function() {
            expect(store.getCount()).toBe(4);
        });
    });
});
```